# Prescriptive Nietzsche

Tags: nietzsche

In all of his works there's always a sense (at least for me) that Nietszche says: "do that, don't do that, don't be like that, be like that".

Did he really wanted us to become better? If that's not the case, why he says, for example, that women's solution to all their problems is to be pregnant? Why he says that to women? And why it seems that he is saying that to us, men, as a way of dealing with them (women)?

And what is übermensch if not something that in a simplistic reading would seem to be something to achieve? (actually, he says that)

What's the purpose of Nietzsche?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of Nietzsche is simple-to make humans more gods and less animals (take into account the fact he comes from the field of classical philology and if you can "summarize" ancient thought the argument goes the ancient thought of humans as something in-between the animals and the gods). However, **the way** to do it is the matter of debate here. Analyzing Nietzsche is never easy (may be because he himself intended to make his thought as difficult to analyze as possible) but to the informed reader Nietzsche always consists somewhat of an anomaly-he seems to be on either sides in every debate. For the argument for women you put forth there is a feminist counterargument-that Nietzsche really didn't meant to offend women as bringing them to the position of inferiority to men by caring for their children only, but he meant to dismiss those women who **choose** (rather than being forced ) to become subordinate to men and uplift the women who actively **choose** to stand by their men as equals and set for themselves higher goals and ultimately purpose in life. Any way you look at Nietzsche it seems every time he says something there is a counterargument to it in his own writings. This is one of the reasons he is so contraversive. Some say it is a reflection of his mental disorder, others say it is brilliance. I guess just like in the case of modern art everybody has to make the argument for him/herself. The point is you can't put labels on Nietzsche (or at least not so easy as you can do it on other philosophers) and the case you have to make for any of his arguments begins and ends with himself in his own writings. The ubermensh can't be put in either "camps" and it is to the interpreter to make his/her own mind as to what the **real** position of Nietzsche is. If you think he is prescriptive then you make your **own** case of it. It isn't Nietzsche who is prescriptive but your **own reaction** as to what he has to say. (At least I think so :). You are free to disagree.)

On the other hand what the purpose of Nietzsche is is a question not yet answered in modern philosophy (and it is doubtful it will ever be answered) but a position you can stick to is Nietzsche is a provocateur of **thought!** he is so unclear, daring, double-edged and a combination of all those traits rarely found in a philosopher to make **you** think! If you think the writing of Nietzsche is meant to make other people **think**, then you can have very "neat" answer of your question. Isn't the ability to **think** what bring us closer to the gods and further from the animals?